# Highcharts: Stop one series interacting with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to have one series *not* interact with the mouse? (e.g. not affect tool tips, marker hovers etc). FOr instance If I want to show average temperature visually, but I want to keep my design simple and not include just the average temperature in my tooltip (Easy), and I want to stop its shape triggering the tooptip (I don't know how to do this)

Comment: do you want to disable tooltip,hover,click for series???

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yWGwB/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `enableMouseTracking` property on the `plotOptions` to `false`.

You can set it both on each separate plot type like this (in this case a line plot):

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        }
```

Or for all plot types like this:

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although not documented, it appears you can switch off mouse tracking at an individual `series` level (not just in `plotOptions`, which applies to all series' of a certain type), like so:

```
  Highcharts.chart({
     ...
     series: [
        ...
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        data: [...]
     ]
  });
```